# Detect duplicates markers using leaflet

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet

I'm creating a map using many geojson overlays caontaining shelters list from many providers. I want group duplicates to have only one marker on tha map, and on the mouse hover display the different providers using some menu like this one : [circular menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-round-and-round.html)

The problem is not the menu, is to know if there is **a way to detect duplicates (by name and distances)**

[Example here.](http://www.refuges.info/nav?zoom=14&lat=42.81981&lon=1.40415&layers=B000000000000TTFFTTFT&scale=27084&baseLayer=Maps.Refuges.info)
If you select Pyrenees-Refuges.com on the Couches menu on the left, you will see duplicates shelters which are over each other. I want to detect they are duplicates.

*This example is using OpenLayers but I'm working on a Leaflet new version*

Answer (score 0):

The [OverlappingMarkerSpiderifier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) plugin does exactly this.

Comment: Not exactly because I have two layers with duplicates. I want to make this effect only when two points (one from each layer) are near and with a similar title.

Comment: That plugin has [an option where you can tune how close the markers must be](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet#construction). You'll need to combine your layers to use this or any other plugin: just set different styles for individual items in the layer.